# My freshly installed Ubuntu Server 15.04 can't connect to filezilla (Plex Mediaserver)

Tags: 15.04, mediaserver, filezilla, plex

Just re-installed ubuntu server on a new hard drive in my mediaserver for Plex.
I used to connect the server to FileZilla to upload files but now it wont connect, and I get this error.

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.0.10:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I used [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jdbwlg0QFc) to help me make it as a friend helped me last time.
I entered the command:

```
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

But I still can't connect, is there anything else I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue in the ports forwarded in your firewall, or with the fact that your server doesn't have a static ip address.